# codeigniter query array the return all rows be send using set_userdata()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am a newbie with codeigniter. I wrote this function but I can only get the last row in the array.  How do I get all the all the rolls so I can pass them to my view.
This is my method:

```
public function resources(){

 $this->load->library('session');

   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM recurso;");

   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){

      $data= $row['example'];
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $this->load->view('recursos');
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by passing them to view. do you want to pass all data to view? or you want to set some data to session?

Answer (score 0):

Well, every time you're doing a loop on `result_array()` of a query you replace `$data` value with current `$row['example']` of the loop, so at the end `$data` will contain information from last row. You can resolve this by using an array. But as long as you don't want to add `0, 1, 2` etc. as keys to session you can assign an array to a specific key and then easily get it (`$this->session->userdata(‘name’)`).

```
public function resources() {
    $this->load->library('session');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM recurso;");

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $infoFromDatabaseArray[] = $row['example'];
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata(array('name' => $infoFromDatabaseArray));

    $data['arrayFromSession`] = $this->session->userdata(‘name’);
    $this->load->view('recursos', $data);
}
```

Then in `.PHP` "recursos" view file you can use:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' . print_r($arrayFromSession) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Keep in mind that (from [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)):

> Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the
>   capacity. The encryption process in particular produces a longer data
>   string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you
>   are storing.

Answer (score 0):

From doc:

ReturnArray()

> This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

It means that you need either pass records to external array or display set them in view in loop. The first option is better.

There are a lot of examples in codeigniter manual. Follow [this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) and you will find more examples

```
$data = array();
$this->load->library('session');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM recurso;");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
  $data[] = $row['example'];

$this->session->set_userdata(array('userdata' => $data));
$this->load->view('recursos');
```

If you in recurso you have only 1 record you shouldn't use loop. In that way you can replace loop with

```
$data = $query->row_array();
```

It will return only one result. More examples you can find in [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Moreover, you made a mistake with setting array to the session.

To do it correctly you need pass an array to `$this->session->set_userdata()` method. You can read more about codeigniter sessions [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the all the rows over to your view, try this

In your controller…

```
$this->load->library('session');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM recurso;");
$this->load->view('recursos');
```

In your view…

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
      <li><?php $row->example ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

### Note

The syntax used in accessing `$row` items has changed. Older versions of codeigniter return arrays. I found that in 2.1.3, it returns an object and must be accessed as such